# Como puedo pasar una variable entre archivos php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, login

Nosé si es la manera correcta, pero luego de varios intentos creo que podria funcionar, yo tengo un sistema de login, y en el archivo verify.php tengo el código para hacer las validaciones, si estan son correctas con la de las base de datos ser redirecciona a la página del menú (En el que solo se podría entrar con la sesión iniciada). Mi problema es que a la hora de redireccionar con la función header hostinger me dá un error, sin embargo nosé que otra manera puedo solucionar el problema.

Con el siguiente código me redirecciona de vuelta a la página de login cuando intento ingresar, como que no se envia la variable del id que se supone se guarda en sessión y al no detectar en las primeras lineas del archivo de main.php me redirecciona a la página de login.

login.php

```
    <form class="form" method="post" action="verify.php">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="name@example.com" name="user">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" name="login_button">Iniciar</button>
    </form>
```

verify.php

```
<?php
// Incluye el archivo connect.php para tener acceso a la conexión a la base de datos
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['login_button'])){
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
        echo "Los campos están vacíos";
    } else {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
        // Utiliza consultas preparadas para prevenir inyecciones SQL
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE user_name = ? AND user_pass = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // Iniciar sesión y redirigir
            //$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;
            header('Location: main.php?user_id='); //Aquí es donde estoy intentando solucionar el problema tratando de enviar directamente la variable por php pero nosé
            //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="main.php"</script>';
            die();
        } else {
            echo "Acceso Denegado";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
// Inicia la sesión
session_start();

// Verifica si el usuario ha iniciado sesión
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}

// Si el usuario ha iniciado sesión, puedes mostrar el contenido de main.php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Necesito saber masomenos como podria solucionarlo....

Comment: Una opción sería usar sesiones. Pero, ten cuidado con la seguridad de tu código, viéndolo como está, es vulnerable a diversos ataques. Para empezar, puedes leer acerca de las [sesiones en el manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) y acerca de vulnerabilidades conocidas y colisiones con MD5 (Para encriptar de usa normalmente librerías como BCrypt) y ataques XSS. Pista: Es altamente recomendable sanitizar los datos de manera correcta con expresiones regulares para evitar inyecciones de código, si bien este es un paso, aún quedan muchos más.

Comment: Mandar por GET el usuario es terrible idea, que pasa si cogen el ID de otro? Porqué quieres manejar  **main** por usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor sería solucionar el problema que te da `header('Location: login.php');`.

No obstante existe una alternativa desde el navegador, que es la [HTML redirections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#html_redirections)

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php

// Verifica si el usuario ha iniciado sesión
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=login.php" />';
    echo '<head></html>';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Y el **session_start()** no tendría que estar antes de iniciar el **HTML**?? Siempre se ha dicho que no debe haber NADA antes de **session_start()**, incluyendo cualquier código HTML.

Comment: @OCHOA La verdad es que nunca había escuchado eso y ni me imagino algún motivo por el cual debe ser así, yo supongo que solo debe estar antes de usar `$_SESSION`. Pero por las dudas he editado la respuesta para colocarlo al inicio

Comment: Es por tema de cabeceras. Cita: "Antes de guardar cualquier información en una sesión es necesario iniciar el manejo se la sesión (session handling). Esto se hace al principio del código PHP, y debe hacerse antes de que que cualquier texto, HTML o JavaScript se envíe al navegador." Otra cita: "Cuando creamos o accedemos al contenido de variables de sesión debemos llamar a la función session_start() antes de cualquier salida de etiquetas HTML."

Comment: @OCHOA Eso mismo estaba leyendo, pero no me queda muy claro. Porque que se coloque HTML o un `echo` no quiere decir que esto se envía al navegador. La pagina se envía al finalizar el código o al hacer un flush.  En la doc oficial tampoco aparece nada de eso (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) y en su explicación tampoco se puede deducir que deba estar antes del todo, solo antes de `$_SESSION` como te había dicho

Comment: De todas maneras voy a investigar el tema, porque me dejaste dudando. En lo poco que he leído en este rato, en muchos lugares recomiendan lo que tu dices

Comment: A lo largo de la historia, muchos errores se han solventado poniendo antes de todo el **session_start()**, es más, ni comentarios es bueno poner antes. Yo por ejemplo, lo primero de todo, en todos mis sistemas es el **session_start()**. Después de mucho aprendí que es lo mejor. Pero es como una regla no escrita y no documentada jejej